# View within a view not updating - Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm having an issue where a datagrid is not reflecting changes to its collection when attached to a view inside a view. More accurately, I have a SecondView within the MainView. On the SecondView I have a datagrid with autogeneratecolumns set to true; when the datagrid is first rendered, it displays the appropriate columns and headers. However, when I populate the list that is attached to it, no changes are reflected.

Here is the complete code for the two views and their respective viewmodels:
MainWindowView:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" x:Name="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" x:Name="Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <views:SecondView/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
namespace MyApp
{
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
internal class MainWindowViewModel : Screen, IShell
{
    Regex expression = new Regex(@"^N\d\.C\d\.D\d\.R\d:\s\s\s-\d"); //ex. "N1.C1.D2.R1:   -3"        
    SecondViewModel svm = new SecondViewModel();        
    public void Open()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        openFile.Multiselect = true;
        openFile.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|Log Files(*.log)|*.log|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        openFile.Title = "Open File(s)";
        bool? userClickedOK = openFile.ShowDialog();
        string[] _fileNames = openFile.FileNames;
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            if (_fileNames != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _fileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    ValidFiles(_fileNames[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void Exit()
    {
        App.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    /* ValidFiles() accepts a string containing a filename and creates a Streamreader that reads the file if it is not a Boxboro file.
     */
    public void ValidFiles(string filename)
    {
        string line;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("Mono Status"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File(s) not supported by this parser. Please select a valid file.");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsMatch(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* IsMatch() accepts a string "input" and determines which parsing method to send the string to, if any.
     * Strings not matching any of the initial criteria are not processed to limit overhead.
     */
    public void IsMatch(string input)
    {
        Match match = expression.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            svm.GetData(input);
        }
    }
}
```

}

SecondWindowView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.SecondView"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         cal:Bind.Model="MyApp.SecondViewModel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyList"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

SecondWindowViewModel:

```
namespace MyApp
{
[Export(typeof(SecondViewModel))]
class SecondViewModel:Screen
{
    Parse parse = new Parse();
    BindableCollection<MyObject> myList = new BindableCollection<MyObject>();
    MyObject myObject;
    public MyObject MyObject
    {
        get { return myObject; }
        set
        {
            myObject = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyList);
        }
    }
    public BindableCollection<MyObject> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
        set 
        { 
            MyList = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MyList);
        }
    }
    public void GetData(string input)
    {
        string[] tempArray = input.Split();
        List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i < tempArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempArray[i]))
            {
                tempList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(tempArray[i]));
            }
        }
        int[] tempIntArray = tempList.ToArray();
        MyObject = new MyObject(tempArray[0], tempIntArray[0], tempIntArray[1], tempIntArray[2], tempIntArray[3]);
        this.MyList.Add(MyObject);

        Console.WriteLine("MyList has " + MyList.Count.ToString() + " elements.");
        //foreach (MyObject item in MyList)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(item.Location);
        //}
    }
}
```

}

Boostrapper:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    internal class AppBootStrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell>
    {
        static AppBootStrapper()
        {
            //Initializes the logger for debugging, remove or comment out in release.
            LogManager.GetLog = type => new DebugLogger(type);
        }
        private CompositionContainer container;
        protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
        {
            this.container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
        }
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            this.container = 
                new CompositionContainer(
                    new AggregateCatalog(
                        AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));
            var batch = new CompositionBatch();
            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            batch.AddExportedValue(this.container);
            this.container.Compose(batch);
        }
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
        }
        //This method is required for the BootStrapper.cs to be discovered.
        protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
            IEnumerable<object> exports = this.container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);
            if (exports.Count() > 0)
            {
                return exports.First();
            }
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }
    }
}
```

Based on my understanding of Caliburn.Micro, whenever the observablecollection MyList is updated (a new item added), the datagrid with x:name MyList should be updated. Even without a data template, I would think I would see a list of blank entries equivalent in length to the number of objects in MyList. When I use this same code in the MainViewModel, rather than in a usercontrol bound to the MainView, I have no issues rendering the list. It seems I'm missing something about updating a view within a view.

I should note, I can verify the list has objects in it by using Console.WriteLine(MyList.Count.ToString()) and watching the output window. I hate asking about these things, every time I do it ends up being a typo or something equally silly, but I've been stuck here for too long.

**NOTE:** Even with MyList.Refresh() thrown in on each iteration, no changes in the datagrid occur.

**NOTE:** It seems like this may answer my question, but I don't understand how to implement it. Perhaps if someone else understands it better, they could put the lines of code in the appropriate places in my code and explain why it works. Thanks in advance. [Caliburn.Micro convention-based bindings not working in nested views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211624/caliburn-micro-convention-based-bindings-not-working-in-nested-views)

Comment: To give the appropriate context: I have used C# since .NET 1.1, but never WPF.  If you are stuck, try this: setup a **very simple** demo application as a proof of concept. The less code the better.  You may find he answer to your question there. Just a thought.

Comment: @Pressaco, I appreciate the advice. This is essentially the expanded version of the simple demo app. My first version was a functional demo that I borrowed, then expanded. In this iteration, I'm trying to implement multiple views so I can incrementally add fucntionality to the views without worrying about the effect on the application as a whole.

Comment: To give the appropriate context, I've used c# for about 6 months, wpf for about 3 and Caliburn.Micro for a couple of weeks :)

Comment: If the simple demo app worked: go back to basics.  Use the demo app and only make the *smallest* of changes to add the second view.  You really want to avoid trying to do too much too fast.  Like I said, I have no experience with WPF... but from what I have read, there is about a 6 month learning curve.

Comment: Just spoke to a colleague that has been developing WPF applications for quite some time now.  If you are new to WPF, he recommends taking a look at: www.drwpf.com

Comment: Did you try using a BindableCollection<T> ?

Comment: Did you figure this one out yet? Can you give the full code for the two viewmodels and XAML for the two views?

Comment: @DerekBeattie, BindableCollection<T> gives me the same result. I will try to post the complete code for the two viewmodels and the xaml for their corresponding views today.

Comment: Looks to me like your SecondView isn't bound to the ViewModel - have you tried the ViewModel composition approach?

Comment: @Charleh, I'm not certain what you mean by it not being bound. With Caliburn.Micro, the framework ties SecondView and SecondViewModel. Additionally, I can safely say that the view sees the viewmodel, because the datagrid gets populated with columns and headers for the properties, just not rows.

Comment: Ok I just can't see the glue needed to apply conventions here ... you are just specifying the sub-view as a nested user control in your main window XAML, but there is no convention to bind the viewmodel to the view.. am I missing something?

Comment: Ah I missed the Bind.Model in your UC!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the instance of the VM is a singleton and you are dealing with the same instance bound to your VM as is doing the file processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this viewmodel first approach - I suspect your inner view isn't being bound (CM doesn't look across control boundaries when applying conventions e.g. it won't apply conventions to nested usercontrols)

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open" x:Name="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" x:Name="Exit"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <!-- Use ContentControl for sub-views, CM will do it's magic if you bind to the VM property using the standard conventions -->
            <ContentControl x:Name="SecondView" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Then in your main:

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : Screen, IShell
{
    Regex expression = new Regex(@"^N\d\.C\d\.D\d\.R\d:\s\s\s-\d"); //ex. "N1.C1.D2.R1:   -3"      
    // Declare your second VM as a property so you can bind to it via CM conventions  
    public SecondViewModel SecondView 
    { 
        get { return _secondView; } 
        set 
        {
            _secondView = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SecondView);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SecondView = new SecondViewModel();
    }
```

CM will automatically inject the right view into the content controls template and setup the datacontext

Alternatively, you can use `Bind.Model` to bind the VM instance to the view which is more a view-first approach

```
   <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <views:SecondView cal:Bind.Model="{Binding SecondView}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

(I think it's Bind.Model and not View.Model but I often get the two mixed up, so failing Bind.Model try View.Model)

Comment: I gave this a go, but it achieves the same result I had before. Columns appear in the datagrid with headers reflecting their respective properties, but the rows are never populated. It seems as if the SecondView only refreshes its appearance when it is loaded, instead of doing so whenever the underlying data changes.

Comment: Check my last comment on your question, only thing I can think of is that you have two instances of SecondViewModel - that might explain it... how have you got MEF setup for this?

Comment: I added the code for the bootstrapper. I'm digging through my code right now to make sure I'm dealing with the same instance of the secondview.

Comment: @spugm1r3 You have logging on, is it complaining about not being to resolve views or view models?

Comment: Also, do the properties on MyObject fire NotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @DerekBeattie, the logs don't have any complaints about resolving the view or viewmodel, here is the log entry for the list: INFO: [2013-04-23T07:11:23.3826619-06:00] Binding Convention Applied: Element MyList. I put breaks in on NotifyOfPropertyChange and only the notification on MyObject fires.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with the multiple instances theory? Your MEF config looks ok to me, but I don't use MEF so I wouldn't notice any nuances. As far as I know `Singleton` is the default lifestyle in MEF

Comment: In MEF for a singleton use: [PartCreationPolicy( CreationPolicy.NonShared)].  Also, you're newing up MyList and exporting it?

Comment: Chain of events looks like this, open a file from the MainWindowView, parse, return the results and display the results in a datagrid on the SecondView. The SecondView is important because the files contain a lot of other information that is sometimes there, sometimes not. I would like to have individual views to allow what ever data exists to be displayed. It also allows me to change the source of the views without affecting the entire application. I know that's not exactly what you asked, but I feel like its important to explain why I'm taking the hard road on this.

Comment: Derek has a point about newing up stuff, you are also newing up SecondViewModel - I don't really use MEF so I can't comment but my understanding is that it does some dependency injection - though you have no public property on the main VM to inject into (and no constructor param). To me it seems like you have a mix of several approaches here - I'd go the VM-first approach but that still doesn't explain why it's not working. Any chance you can attach a demo project showing the issue?

Comment: @Charleh, **UPDATE:** I tried your solution again in a demo project that simplified things a bit by taking the demo from http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Basic%20Configuration%2c%20Actions%20and%20Conventions&referringTitle=Documentation and placing it in a nested view. For the demo, your solution works great. So it appears I need to revisit my own code and verify a couple of things. I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer, and I'll post a new question if the problem is external to this. Thanks for your help.